# Sort vectors according to their distance between them

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I have a collection of vectors, let`s say $n$ vectors. I am trying to find an easy way to SORT these vectors in that way that after sorting of vectors $(V_1,V_2,...,V_n)$ the first vector $V_1$ and the last vector $V_n$ will be two furthest vectors. Next $V_{n-1}$ will be the second farthest vector from the $V_1$. $V_{n-2}$ will be the third furthest vector from the $V_1$...and so on. Is there a good algorithm or an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: perhaps I understand your question wrongly, but couldn't you just choose an arbitrary vector to be $V_1$, find the distances of all the other vectors to $V_1$ and then simply sort them according to their distances away from $V_1$?

Comment: Clarification is necessary--by two farthest vectors do you mean $\max_{i,j}||V_i - V_j||_2$? (Which may not even be a unique pair in general.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find two furthest vectors, compute the convex hull and find needed two points on it, it is O(n log n) in summary.

Comment: $V_1$ is not known to begin with, so "choosing" $V_1$ is the question.

Comment: Any vector can be $V_1$.

Comment: In the question, $V_1$ and $V_n$ are the (likely) unique pair that have the greatest distance. So $V_1$ here is not arbitrary. I do not see a better way than searching all pair distances to find them...

Comment: Okay. Is the distance a metric?

Comment: If yes - edited a post.

Comment: Thnx for your answers. Actually what I am trying to do is simply find all distances between each possible pair in the collection of vectors and then V1 and Vn will be the two vectors which has the greatest distance in between. Ex: if dist(V1,V2) = 3; dist(V1,V3) = 45, dist(V2,V4) = 100... then the farthest vectors here are V2 and V4.  then based on this we can sort all the other vectors using V2 as a reference vector. Of course doing this for a huge number of vectors take too much time. I thought maybe there should be a better way.

Comment: @Harold.I know nothing about convex hull. If Convex Hull is a good way then I have to read about it. If you have a good reference(paper or book or link or whatever) could you please let us know? Thnx for the answer

Comment: @xXx the Graham scan I believe is what Harold is referring. If you have many $V$ then I think that is what you need. I do not know if the O(n log n) applies for anything other than $V \in \mathbb{R}^2$. I will leave that for you to research...