# Sorting Vectors based on their correlation

Tags: correlation, sorting

This problem [question]: [Sort vectors according to their distance between them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338646/sort-vectors-according-to-their-distance-between-them) is about sorting vectors based on the distance between them. What about sorting vectors based on the correlation coefficient between them. What I want to do is to sort vectors based on their "importance" in the dataset. If we have N vectors then the sorting will be V1,V2,...,Vn where V1 and Vn are less correlated then the others. V1 and V2 are most correlated whith each other...and so on. I was thinking to use pearsons coefficient as a correlation coefficient. Is this possible or do you have any idea about this issue? And is there a good algorithm to do this or we should find the correlating coefficient between each pair of vectors and then find two less correlated ones and then sort all the vectors in between the two less correlated.

Thnx for reading and answering :)

Comment: "V1 and Vn are less correlated then the others. V1 and V2 are most correlated whith each other...and so on." Does not make much sense to me. That does not define an order. Imagine you are given N cities in a country, you are asked to sort them such that cities C_1 and C_2 are nearest, "and so on". How would you do that?

Comment: as I understand your question I would find two farthest cities (C_1 and C_n or example) and then I would use C_1 as the reference point. Meaning that C_2 would be the nearest city to the C_1...and so on.Is this what you asked for? This is when distance is used as a metric. Read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601320/sorting-vectors-based-on-their-correlation.

Comment: Well, you could certainly do that, but that's rather ah-hoc/arbitrary, and it's not normally considered a "sort" (for one thing, $C_1$ and $C_n$ could be reversed; there is no "order" there). This also applies to your linked question.

Comment: yes but it takes too much time. You are right. Well what I want to do tis to find somehow the "most important" vectors and try to accomodate them in SOM(self organizing map) if you know about this algorithm. Actually after training in this algorithm vectors are grouped based on their correlation. So I was thinking that if I initalize the map with vectors which are more correlated then maybe I will reduce the number of iterations in SOM.

Comment: Yes, what I first thought was "this is like a Kohonen map, rather than a sorting". Perhaps you should read about correlation as a measure of distance in relation with clustering, eg http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Visualization/cor-cluster/index.htm

Comment: From the title it seems a great article and completely related to what I want. I will read it and see if I can use it in my purpose. Thnx a lot.